# How do I set a boolean condition to clear or close the turtle program based on user input?

Tags: python, boolean, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I have created a for loop to run this Turtle graphic. I am trying to create a condition which is set to run the turtle program if the user answers 'yes' (y) or close, or clear the program if the user answers 'no' (n). I have tried calling the t.clear() and done() functions separately after 'answer = False' but this doesn't seem to work. The program runs anyway, even if the user inputs 'n' and hits enter in the console. Do I need to set up return(y, n)?

```
from turtle import *
import turtle as t

shape('turtle')
speed(15)

# First you need to define a loop function to draw a square
def square():
    for i in range(4):
        t.color('white')
        t.bgcolor('turquoise')
        t.forward(150)
        t.right(90)

# Ask the user for input if they wish to see the Turtle move
question = input("Do you wish to see my animation? y/n: ")
answer = bool(question)
y = True
n = False
if answer == y: 
    answer = True

    for i in range(60):
        square()
        t.right(6)

else: 
    answer = False
    t.clear()

done()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making the assumption that `bool()` called on `"Yes"` or `"No"` returns a boolean value:

```
answer = bool(question)
```

It doesn't.  Since both are non-empty strings, it returns `True` for either.  Instead, we can use a boolean expression to get the result you desire, and it requires less code to do so:

```
import turtle

# First you need to define a loop function to draw a square
def square():
    for side in range(4):  # unused variable
        turtle.forward(150)
        turtle.right(90)

# Ask the user for input if they wish to see the Turtle move
question = input("Do you wish to see my animation? y/n: ")
answer = question.lower() in ('y', 'yes')

turtle.shape('turtle')
turtle.speed('fastest')

if answer:
    turtle.bgcolor('turquoise')
    turtle.color('white')

    for repetition in range(60):  # unused variable
        square()
        turtle.right(6)

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.done()
```

Comment: So because each answer returned string values this evaluates to a True expression, whereas an empty string value returns a False expression?

Comment: @LynStanford, yes.  Empty strings and empty containers are `False` in a boolean context.